# Removing objects by date parameter.

Tags: javascript

How can i remove objects where `txnDate` is not from current start year `01/01/2016 till current date 08/05/2016.`

```
[{
    "site": "One",
    "txnDate": "01/19/2015",
   }, {
    "site": "Two",
    "txnDate": "01/25/2016",   
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "01/26/2014",    
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "09/05/2016",    
}]
```

I want the array to contain only one object.

```
[{
    "site": "Two",
    "txnDate": "01/25/2016",   
}]
```

I am not sure how to approach this, usually i do a filter by dateFrom and dateTo...

```
arr.filter(function (el) {
   return el.txnDate <= "01/01/2016" &&
             el.txnDate >= "08/05/2016";
});
```

Comment: your way is right, except you'll need to convert those strings into `Date` objects

Comment: Agree about converting to date or delivering your dates is yyyyMMdd format for string comparison.  Your parameters may not be quite right.  You'll never have a txnDate that is both less than 01/01/2016 and greater than 08/05/2016.

Comment: If you want to sort/filter on dates in string format, you need the YYYY-MM-DD format to get it correct. But it's usually better to convert them to a date and then compare the getTime().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there:

```js
var arr = [{
    "site": "One",
    "txnDate": "01/19/2015",
   }, {
    "site": "Two",
    "txnDate": "01/25/2016",   
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "01/26/2014",    
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "09/05/2016",    
}];

var startTs = (new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1)).getTime(),
    endTs = Date.now();

var res = arr.filter(function (el) {
  var ts = (new Date(el.txnDate)).getTime();
  return ts >= startTs && ts <= endTs;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dates in JavaScript may be compared easily with > = etc. operators, as they are coerced into a number when comparing. Parse your values as dates and you already got it:

```js
var arr = [{
    "site": "One",
    "txnDate": "01/19/2015",
   }, {
    "site": "Two",
    "txnDate": "01/25/2016",   
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "01/26/2014",    
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "09/05/2016",    
}];

var arr = arr.filter(function (el) {
  var date = Date.parse(el.txnDate);
   return date >= new Date("01/01/2016") && date <= new Date();
});
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr[0])
```

Comment: Dates in Javascript are Objects, not Numbers. They can be coerced to different types. Try the following code: `var d = new Date("01/01/2016"); console.log(d + 0); console.log(d - 0);`. On the other hand, `d.getTime()` _is_ a number.

Comment: @Arnauld You're totally right. Thx for the correction.

Comment: No worries. Just as a side note, you may want to use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to explicitly convert the freshly created dates into timestamps: `var d = +new Date("01/01/2016");`. That would eliminate any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close actually, you need to parse the strings to an actual `Date` object first to compare. It's easier if you create variables for your lower and upper bounds as well.

```js
const myDates = [{
    "site": "One",
    "txnDate": "01/19/2015",
   }, {
    "site": "Two",
    "txnDate": "01/25/2016",   
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "01/26/2014",    
}, {
    "site": "Three",
    "txnDate": "09/05/2016",    
}];

//Upper and lower ranges.
const lowerDate = new Date(2016, 00, 01);
const upperDate = new Date(Date.now());

const goodDates = myDates.filter(item => {
  const currentDate = new Date(item.txnDate); //Current date object
  return lowerDate <= currentDate && currentDate <= upperDate //Only add things within our range
});

console.log(goodDates);
```

Note that I used `const` for every variable/object. This ensures that the objects can't be mutated at a later point, making sure they're set. If you want them to be mutable (changeable), change the variable declaration to `let`.